# UIWebView and retina displays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

Hi Guys got an issue with a UIWebView,

The basics of it is that I am trying to display an image strip. So the image would be 5000x640 (landscape) so it would display the whole image in a UIWebView that can be scrolled across.

The issue I am having is that If i use scaleToFit, it scales the whole page (and not just the height). On all other displays aside from the retina displays this problem doesnt occur.

What am I missing, the image is 2x as big on the UIWebView of any 4th gen device. How can either scale the content (height only) or have the UIWebView be treated as scaled by 2x?

Comment: - [Earlier discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031537/using-retina-images-in-a-local-uiwebview)

- [Injecting javascript to change the page properties.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio)